# Meu aplicativo esta fechando ao iniciar a tela com banco de dados

Tags: android

Minha `activity` com o banco de dados está com algum problema, pois criei a `class` certo e o Android Studio não esta mostrando nenhum erro, mas quando vou executar ele no celular ao abrir `activity` que tem o banco de dados ele fecha.

Alguem teria alguma ideia do que seja?

package BancoSimples (banco)

## SimplesBanco

```
package BancoSimples;

import com.allsport.miyonic.allsport.SimplesHome;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class SimplesBanco implements Serializable{
    public long id;
    public String timeum;
    public String timedois;
    public String golone;
    public String goldois;


    public SimplesBanco(long id, String timeum, String timedois, String golone, String goldois){
        this.id = id;
        this.timeum = timeum;
        this.timedois = timedois;
        this.golone = golone;
        this.goldois = goldois;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return timeum;
    }
}
```

## SimplesRepositorio

```
package BancoSimples;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

public class SimplesRepositorio {

    private SimplesSQLHelper helper;

    public SimplesRepositorio(Context ctx) {
        helper = new SimplesSQLHelper(ctx);
    }

    private long inserir(SimplesBanco simplao) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

        cv.put(SimplesSQLHelper.COLUNA_NOMEONE, simplao.timeum);
        cv.put(SimplesSQLHelper.COLUNA_NOMETWO, simplao.timedois);
        cv.put(SimplesSQLHelper.COLUNA_GOLONE, simplao.golone);
        cv.put(SimplesSQLHelper.COLUNA_GOLTWO, simplao.goldois);

        long id = db.insert(SimplesSQLHelper.TABELA_SIMPLES, null, cv);
        if (id != -1) {
            simplao.id = id;
        }

        db.close();
        return id;
    }

    public void salvar(SimplesBanco simplao) {
        if (simplao.id == 0) {
            inserir(simplao);
    }
 }
}
```

## SimplesSQLHelper

```
package BancoSimples;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;


public class SimplesSQLHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String NOME_BANCO = "dbsimples";

    private static final int VERSAO_BANCO = 1;

    public static final String TABELA_SIMPLES = "result";
    public static final String COLUNA_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COLUNA_NOMEONE = "timeum";
    public static final String COLUNA_NOMETWO = "timedois";
    public static final String COLUNA_GOLONE = "golone";
    public static final String COLUNA_GOLTWO = "goldois";


    public SimplesSQLHelper(Context context){
        super(context, NOME_BANCO, null, VERSAO_BANCO);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase){
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(
                "CREATE TABLE " + TABELA_SIMPLES + "(" + COLUNA_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + COLUNA_NOMEONE + "TEXT NOT NULL,"
                        + COLUNA_NOMETWO + "TEXT NOT NULL," + COLUNA_GOLONE + "TEXT NOT NULL," + COLUNA_GOLTWO + "TEXT NOT NULL)"
        );
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int oldVersion, int newVersion){
        //para as proximas versões
    }
}
```

## activity_simples.xml

```
import BancoSimples.SimplesBanco;
import BancoSimples.SimplesRepositorio;
import BancoSimples.SimplesSQLHelper;

public void SalvarR (SimplesBanco simplao){
        SimplesRepositorio repo = new SimplesRepositorio(this);
        repo.salvar(simplao);
        setResult(RESULT_OK);
    }
```

Comment: falta postar o log de erro, veja no LogCat e poste aqui novamente

Answer (score 1):

Nathan

Fica muito difícil descobrir o erro sem o log, mas vamos tentando ir mexendo pra ver onde está o erro. Primeiro, vamos dar uma corrigida nessa sua SQL de criação de tabela, pois está faltando uns espaços nela durante a concatenação da string com as variáveis>

```
"CREATE TABLE " + TABELA_SIMPLES + "(" + COLUNA_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + COLUNA_NOMEONE + "TEXT NOT NULL,"
                    + COLUNA_NOMETWO + "TEXT NOT NULL," + COLUNA_GOLONE + "TEXT NOT NULL," + COLUNA_GOLTWO + "TEXT NOT NULL)"
```

Vamos observar o trecho `COLUNA_NOMEONE + "TEXT NOT NULL,"`, quando concatenar, não vai ter espaço entre o nome da coluna e o tipo TEXT, ficando como resultado algo do tipo `colunaumTEXT NOT NULL`. Observe que tem vários casos assim na sua SQL acima.

Qualquer coisa se só isso não resolver, comente aqui embaixo pra irmos descobrindo.

Comment: Ola amigo... desculpa pela demora da resposta do comentario.... entao vou seguir a sua dica, mas estou com um plano de começar tudo de novo achei uma playlist no youtube... caso não consiga tento ajuda de vocês... mas obrigado mesmo pela atençao sua.... mas vou fazer seu esquema primeiro :)